# How to replace id values in array with their actual values stored in another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two associative arrays, one with data about states (or provinces) and one with different countries.  I'm getting the values from a relational database so the states array doesn't hold the country name but rather the country id.

States Array:

```
array(3) {
  array {
    'name' => 'Alabama',
    'country' => 1},
  array {
    'name' => 'Alberta',
    'country' => 2},
  array {
    'name' => 'Minnesota',
    'country' => 1}
}
```

Countries Array:

```
array(2) {
    1 => 'United States',
    2 => 'Canada'
}
```

The result I want is:

```
array(3) {
  array {
    'name' => 'Alabama',
    'country' => 'United States'},
  array {
    'name' => 'Alberta',
    'country' => 'Canada'},
  array {
    'name' => 'Minnesota',
    'country' => 'United States'}
}
```

I searched and searched and haven't found a question that answers this specific problem.  I'm sure I'm not the only one who has data like this; maybe I'm not looking for the right terms.  I did write a function in my Country model class to solve this but I'm thinking there has to be a more efficient way.

---

My current solution (it works but there's probably a better way, right?):

```php
function replaceKeyValues($replaceArray,$replaceKey)
  {
  $countries = $this->get_countries();
  foreach ($replaceArray as &$itm) {
    if (isset($itm[$replaceKey])) {
      if (in_array($itm[$replaceKey], array_flip($countries))) {
        $itm[$replaceKey] = $countries[$itm[$replaceKey]];
      }
    }
  }
  return $replaceArray;
}

//called like this (for example)
$states = $this->Country->replaceKeyValues($states,'country');
```

---

**Edit:** I ended up using Jon's suggestion and also slightly modified the original function to make it generic enough that I don't need it in my model class anymore.  It's now in one of my helper classes, and I added another input parameter which is the "master data" array.  Hopefully this helps someone :-)

```php
function replaceKeyValues($masterArray,$replaceArray,$replaceKey)
{
    foreach ($replaceArray as &$itm) {
        if (isset($itm[$replaceKey])) {
            if (isset($masterArray[$itm[$replaceKey]])) {
                $itm[$replaceKey] = $masterArray[$itm[$replaceKey]];
            }
        }
    }
    return $replaceArray;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you do that part of it in your SQL if it's from a relational DB? (Out of curiosity)

Comment: @Jon It's a fair question (and an option that I've debated, since my background is actually more SQL centric that php) but I figured that I'd try to keep my model classes table-specific (I'm currently using an ActiveRecord paradigm).  I'm not sure if this is the right approach or if I should join to all my "detail" tables in my "master" model to get this info.  I'd be more than happy to hear your thoughts (and others) on this topic.

Comment: Fair enough, though, will the states model and the country model be used separately in another application?  Because if not, it's something that can be combined when building your array rather than modifying the array later to add the functionality, and would be quicker to do in a SQL `join` than it would be walking through the array. :) If both models are made to be used separately, then that is a fantastic way to do it ^^

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to build it to be somewhat extendable in the future.  There may be a RESTful API soon and in my application many of the models will be used both separately and in coordination with others.  I'm not actually using States and Countries either - I just thought it was an example that everyone could relate to.  Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the fact that this

```
if (in_array($itm[$replaceKey], array_flip($countries)))
```

would be much better written as

```
if (isset($countries[$itm[$replaceKey]]))
```

and the fact that the nested conditions can be de-nested, this is basic enough that there's no real opportunity for improvement.

You could of course replace the `foreach` with `array_walk` and a lambda, but that wouldn't be any "better".

Comment: Thanks @Jon!  The array_flip() is what I felt the most 'dirty' about.  I needed another set of (much more experienced eyes) on it :-)